# Curl OR file_get_contents Request : Return Captcha Verification

Tags: php, iframe, curl

I am copying a song (IFRAME code) From other site (Like Youtube) Into My site, (Its Legal to copy iframe code)

Using get `file_get_contents($url)`;
OR `CURL`

> after 250 URL `file_get_contents` Not working, Return Captcha Verification
>
> and URL (from 250 to 500) Urls `CURL` not working : Return Empty

Both are not working after 500 urls,

What i do to verify I am not a robort.

MY file_get_contents CODE is :

```
function getf($url){
    $ctx = stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array('timeout' => 50))
    );
    $html = file_get_contents($url, 0,$ctx);
    return $html;
}
```

OR CURL CODE,,,

```
function curlm($url){
        $toSet[CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT] = 20; // Time to wait for connection
        $toSet[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT] = 50; // Time to wait for whole operation
        $toSet[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = true; // Return transfer instead of printing
        $toSet[CURLOPT_FAILONERROR] = true;
        //
        $toSet[CURLOPT_USERAGENT] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        //
        // Show SSL without verifying
        $toSet[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
        $toSet[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = false;
        //
        // Start curl
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        //
        // Load options
        curl_setopt_array($curl, $toSet);
        //
        // Fetch page
        $return = curl_exec($curl);

        // Check for curl errors
        if ( $error = curl_error($curl) )
            echo 'ERROR: ',$error;

        curl_close($curl);
        return $return;
}
```

I need Full HTML code , If you know any other way to get Full HTML for unlimited URL please Tell me

OR

> Alternative of `get_file_content` or `Curl` that get html from another Server

OR

Please Give Solution in any one of function or Both, that work on millions URL with out return Captcha verfication

After 1 hour Again both are start working... But i want continues file content

> If i clean cache or use proxy , still get_file_content Return : Captcha verification and Curl return empty,
>
> I am sure response server Block my Domain Server IP For 1 hour;